# Automatic font scale using REM

Tags: mobile, font-size

I'm testing something out and it is maybe a little bit weird but i'm confused. 
Why is this not "scaling" on my  iphone screen? I thought the rem property would make text smaller/bigger dependent on what screen you use? This is the code.

```
html
    {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
h1
    {
        font-size:62px;
        font-size:4.42rem;
    }
```

---

```
...
<body>
<h1>This text is going to be smaller on an iphone screen.</h1>
</body>
..
```

Answer (score 0):

An article from Snook.ca talks about the REM units: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

In his closing statement:

> And voila, we now have consistent and predictable sizing in all browsers, and resizable text in the current versions of all major browsers.

Maybe that's what is happening in your case?